"Save a PDF of completed survey response to a File Upload field" in REDCap - How are these files named?
I have enabled the "Save a PDF of completed survey response to a File Upload field" option for one of my surveys to add it to a paperwork collection form in the same project, but when I check a test record the uploaded PDF name is the date and a random series of numbers (see pics below.) Is there any way to change how these particular PDFs are named?



I don't know if you can rename it, but I have my doubts that the 1146 is random. It looks like it might be the time.

Also, you may want to upload a new image. There is a name visible next to "Editing existing Record ID 6399"
